# How do I retrieve contact details for specifc SMS Message?

Tags: java, android

How do I get the contact details of the sender of an SMS? I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve the photo of a sender, but when I attempt to grab sender details for the sms message, it returns either NULL or 0:

```
String number = getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
```

That code is in a while loop, where I get all messages stored on the device and attempt to extract sender details for processing.

Comment: You need to call `getString()` on the Cursor: `String number = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);

            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                String body = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString();
                String address = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                String contactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("person")).toString();

                if (contactId != null) {

                    InputStream inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts
                            .openContactPhotoInputStream(getActivity().getContentResolver(), ContentUris
                                    .withAppendedId(
                                            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                                            Long.valueOf(contactId)));

                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        Bitmap photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                    }

                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                c.close();
```